# Prove that a function $f(n)$ counting the number of odd divisors multiplicative

Tags: elementary-number-theory

How can I show that $f(n)$ is multiplicative, where $f(n)$ represents the number of the divisors of n in the form $2k + 1$?

I'm studying algebra and I came across some questions on multiplicative functions (which should be number theory though), but there is any worked example of such proof. Can you help?

Comment: Welcome to MSE!  When you post a question, try to give context and explain what you have tried so far. Among other things, this helps to ensure that you receive useful answers that are at the correct level. You can edit this post to include additional details, such as an attempt to solve the problem or a description of why you are having trouble.

Answer (score 3):

If $a$ and $b$ are coprime, every odd divisor of $ab$ can be written in exactly one way as the product of an odd divisor of $a$ and and odd divisor of $b$, and every such product is an odd divisor of $ab$.  So $f(ab) = f(a) f(b)$.

Comment: Well, you stated what is to be proven... maybe a hint could help? =)

Comment: ... prime factorization...

Answer (score 0):

First note $f(1)=1$, then let compute $f(2^k)= 1$.

Note that the total number of divisors function is $\tau(n)$ which is multiplicative, so considering if $n=2^km$ with $m$ odd, we can see that $f(n)=f(m)$, so

$$f(2^km)={\tau(n)\over \tau(2^k)}=\tau(m)$$

and we know $\tau$ is multiplicative.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, multiplicative only means for relatively prime integers $m$ and $n$. The integers $m$ and $n$ can be expressed as a product of primes: $m = 2^{a_1} {p_2}^{a_2} {p_3}^{a_3} ... {p_n}^{a_n}$. $n = 2^{b_1}{q_2}^{b_2} {q_3}^{b_3} ... {q_n}^{b_n}$.Note that $p_i \not= q_i$ for any $i$ because m and n are relatively prime [$a_1$ or $b_1$ is $0$, and all other powers are nonzero].

We thus can consider the set $p_2, p_3 .... p_n, q_2, .... q_n$ to obtain all odd factors. (We removed factors that are a multiple of 2). It will be easier if we rename the elements of the set, calling the $i$th element as $s_i$. So we must find the power set of the set $\{ s_1, s_2, ......... s_{2n-2}\}$. [the null set takes the role of $1$ which is not a product of primes]. So $f(mn) = (2n-1)C0 + (2n-2)C 1 + (2n-2)C2 + ... (2n-2) C (2n-2) = (1+1)^{2n-2} = 2^{2n-2}$.

Okay. Now, $f(m) = 2^{(n-1)}$ and $f(n) = 2^{(n-1)}$ [I hope you can see why, by applying the same technique], and we have shown that $f(mn) = 2^{2n-2}$. Thus, $f(mn) = f(m)f(n)$.